# Ruby - how to test method using minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have this class:

```
require 'yaml'

class Configuration
  class ParseError < StandardError; end

  attr_reader :config

  def initialize(path)
    @config = YAML.load_file(path)
  rescue => e
    raise ParseError, "Cannot open config file because of #{e.message}"
  end

  def method_missing(key, *args, &block)
    config_defines_method?(key) ? @config[key.to_s] : super
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
    config_defines_method?(method_name) || super
  end

  private

  def config_defines_method?(key)
    @config.has_key?(key.to_s)
  end
end
```

how do I write test for methods: method_missing, respond_to_missing?, config_defines_method?
I have some understanding about unit testing but when it comes to Ruby im pretty new.

So far i have tried this:

```
def setup
  @t_configuration = Configuration.new('./config.yaml')
end

def test_config_defines_method
  @t_configuration.config[:test_item] = "test"
  assert @t_configuration.respond_to_missing?(:test_item)
end
```

Im not sure if im testing it right, because when i run rake test it gives me this:

> NoMethodError: private method `respond_to_missing?' called for #

If there is no clear way how to solve this, can anyone direct me to a place where similar tests are written? So far Ive only found hello world type of test examples which are not helping much in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation for `#respond_to_missing?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing), you do not want to call the method directly. Instead, you want to check that the object responds to your method. This is done using the `#respond_to?` method:

```
assert @t_configuration.respond_to?(:test_item)
```

Comment: thanks, so now i know that it is some kind of default method inherited for all objects